# Is there action center on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, 32-bit

I know this is a very simple/noobie question, but is there action center on Windows Server 2008? I've looked everywhere for it. Does anyone know a way to enable it?

The OS is: Windows Server 2008 R1 SP2 32 Bit

Thanks,
Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is there action center on Windows Server 2008?`

No, there isn't.